# SQL Query with specific ID/row on Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to print my data with specific ID by using SELECT * FROM query and I have problem with my query.
Example, i have table called **tb_pasien** , and it has 8 columns :
 **kode_pasien(as ID), nama_pasien, email_pasien, alamat_pasien, tanggal_lahir, umur, jenis_kelamin and no_telp.**

So, when I want to print someone data it will *only show her/his data* not all data on my table.

This is my code :

**Model**

```
public function view_kartu()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_pasien where kode_pasien='$kode_pasien' LIMIT 1");
    return $query;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function cetakkartu() {  
    // Load all views as normal
    $data['pasien'] = $this->a_model->view_kartu();
    $this->load->view('cetak-kartu', $data);
    // Get output html
    $html = $this->output->get_output();

    // Load library
    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');

    // Convert to PDF
    $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
    $this->dompdf->render();
    $this->dompdf->stream("cetak-kartu" . ".pdf", array ('Attachment' => 0));

}
```

**View**

```
 <table border="1" width="100%">
      <tr>

        <th>Kode Pasien</th>
        <th>Nama Pasien</th>    
        <th>Email Pasien</th>
        <th>Alamat Pasien</th>
        <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
        <th>Umur</th>
        <th>JK</th>
        <th>No. Telp</th>
      </tr>

      <?php
      if( ! empty($pasien)){

          foreach($pasien as $data){
            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>".$data->kode_pasien."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$data->nama_pasien."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$data->email_pasien."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$data->alamat_pasien."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$data->tanggal_lahir."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$data->umur."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$data->kode_jk."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$data->no_telp."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

          }
      }
      ?>
      </table>
```

But when i try to print it, it shows empty result. Can someone help me? Thankyou.

Comment: You are using `$kode_pasien` which is not declared...

Comment: Are you sure you getting the value of the variable $kode_pasien in the model. Just try try to print / echo your query inside the model and you will get to know the problem. You should pass the variable $kode_paisen .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your model function as below -

```
  public function view_kartu($kode_paisen)
   {
       $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_pasien where    kode_pasien='$kode_pasien' LIMIT 1");
    return $query;
  }
```

And then from your controller, call it as -

```
public function cetakkartu() {  

     //set a value for $kode_paisen
     $kode_paisen = "XXX";  //set here whatever you like.

    // Load all views as normal . See here we passing the variabke in the function.
    $data['pasien'] = $this->a_model->view_kartu($kode_paisen);
    // Rest of your function ...
}
```

As an example, i have a table "currency" in my site and this is how i fetch all the currencies mapped to a particular company in Code Igniter model.

```
function getCurrencyList($companyId)
    {

        $sql = "select currency_id from company_currency where company_id = $companyId";
        $retVal = $this->db->query($sql);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() == 0)
        {

            return null;

        }
        if($retVal && $this->db->affected_rows() > -1)
        {
            if($retVal->result_array())
            {
                foreach($retVal->result_array() as $row)
                {
                    $arrCurrencyId[] = $row['currency_id'];
                }
            }
            return $arrCurrencyId;
        }
        else
        {
            log_message('error', mysql_error()." ******* at function getActionList Role Model *********");
            return null;
        }               
    }
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: $kode_paisen = "XXX"; <-- when i set a value here example $kode_paisen = "4"; , it will only show user with ID number 4 . what should i do?

Comment: If you want all the data from the table then don't use `where` or `limit`. For example `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_pasien");`

Comment: no, no~~ i wont to show all of my data from table. just like i said before  I want to print someone data and  it will only show her/his data not all data on my table. @DFriend

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you want.

Comment: lets say, i have data in my table like this : kode_pasien=1, name_pasien=john, email_pasien=john@xxx.com and kode_pasien=2, name_pasien=mark, email_pasien=mark@xxx.com, i want to show john data only not all data in my table. @Dfriend

Comment: OK. The above answer does that. If you pass a value of `1` to `view_kartu` it will return the data for john.

Comment: and how to show mark's data? if i setting a value it will return whatever i set on value. did i need to change my value whenever i want to show someone data? @DFriend

Comment: That is a new and different question. But... It depends on how your site lets the user select which user to display. You don't show any code for that. One way is to pass a variable to the controller. `public function cetakkartu($kode_paisen) { ...`  and remove the line `$kode_paisen = "XXX";`. The URL to show john would be `example.com/controller_name/cetakkartu/1` and the URL to show mark would be `example.com/controller_name/cetakkartu/2`

Comment: can u see on my other post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229483/print-show-one-row-only-from-my-table-codeigniter @DFriend

Answer (score 0):

Need to the return result array or row but not query (as per your requirement of fetching data from array or array object)

Like this

return $query->result_array();
                or

return $query->row();

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
$this->db->select('kode_pasien as ID, nama_pasien, email_pasien, alamat_pasien, tanggal_lahir, umur, jenis_kelamin, no_telp');
$this->db->from('tb_pasien');
$data= $this->db->get()->result_array();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);die;
```